# How to ensure function is type-stable and allocation-free

Tags: types, julia, allocation

I am writing a function and I’m trying to ensure that it is type-stable and allocation-free. I am using the @code_warntype to check for type-stability and @btime to determine memory allocation.

Here is my function:

```
# we assume u is a 2 x num_particles matrix
function rhs!(du, u, parameters, t) 
    C = parameters
    v_x(x, y, t) = -sin(pi * y) * cos(pi * t / C)
    v_y(x, y, t) =  sin(pi * x) * cos(pi * t / C)
    
    num_particles = size(u, 2)
    for i in 1:num_particles
        C = parameters
        du[1, i] = v_x(u[1, i], u[2, i], t)
        du[2, i] = v_y(u[1, i], u[2, i], t)
        
    end
    
end

using BenchmarkTools; @btime rhs!(du,u,parameters,t)
@code_warntype rhs!(du,u,parameters,t)
```

How do I modify the function to make it allocation free and type-stable?

Answer (score 1):

Besides commenting out the `C = parameters` line, there are other changes which make your function much faster and type-stable. `sin(pi * x)` and `cos(pi * x)` can suitably be written as `sinpi(x)` and `cospi(x)`, respectively. It is faster and more accurate. Also, `v_x` and `v_y` functions depend on two variables only, the third variable can be removed. Finally, add the `C` variable as input to the functions explicitly, then you can move the functions out of `rhs!` freely.

This is 18X faster than original with zero allocations.

```
# we assume u is a 2 x num_particles matrix
function rhs!(du, u, parameters, t) 
    C = parameters
    v_x(y, t, C) = -sinpi(y) * cospi(t / C)
    v_y(x, t, C) =  sinpi(x) * cospi(t / C)
    
    num_particles = size(u, 2)
    for i in 1:num_particles
        # C = parameters
        du[1, i] = v_x(u[2, i], t, C)
        du[2, i] = v_y(u[1, i], t, C)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete the assignment to `C` into the loop. I assume this confuses inference since it sees `C` being assigned later which in general could cause the return type of `v_x` and `v_y` to change, although that's not the case here.

```
function rhs!(du, u, parameters, t) 
    C = parameters
    v_x(x, y, t) = -sin(pi * y) * cos(pi * t / C)
    v_y(x, y, t) =  sin(pi * x) * cos(pi * t / C)
    
    num_particles = size(u, 2)
    for i in 1:num_particles
        # C = parameters <-- delete this
        du[1, i] = v_x(u[1, i], u[2, i], t)
        du[2, i] = v_y(u[1, i], u[2, i], t)
    end
    
end
```